# Using composePanorama in Stitcher class with OpenCV-Python bindings

Tags: python, opencv, opencv-stitching

I'm trying to estimate transform for some images and stitch them using `stitcher.estimateTransform()` and `stitcher.composePanorama()` in  python. After estimating transform, composePanorama gives the error as below:

> pano is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

I tried to convert NumPy Array into a Mat object using `cv2.fromarray(left)`, but it only works for cv, not cv2. Therefore how can I convert this numpy to MAT array in cv2. I don't find any examples of using `composePanorama` with python bindings. Any solution for this error or example of using `stitcher.estimateTransform()` with OpenCV-Python bindings would be appreciated.

**Note**: Although Stitching class in OpenCV-Python bindings is not complete (beacuse of auto-generated bindings), `help(cv2.createStitcher())` demonstrates that it contains `composePanorama()` and `estimateTransform()`.

**Note**: I can use `stitcher.stitch()` without any problems, but using `stitcher.stitch()` does not help me, because I'm trying to not calculate the transform for each iteration in the main loop.

My simple code :

```
leftStream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
rightStream = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
left = leftStream.read()[1]
right = rightStream.read()[1]
st = cv2.createStitcher(False)
st.estimateTransform([left, right])
st.composePanorama([left, right])
```

Answer (score 3):

To use `stitcher.estimateTransform()` and `stitcher.composePanorama()` you will need to

1. Download opencv https://github.com/opencv/opencv
2. navigate to opencv-master/modules/stitching/include/opencv2/stitching.hpp
3. add CV_WRAP in front of any methods you want to be able to call in Python. In this case those would be estimateTransform and composePanorama

Then to build the python module:

```
cd ~/opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
sudo make install
```

Then move the module to your virtual environment from wherever it was installed to. In my case that was /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.

See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/17/install-opencv-4-on-macos/ and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/df6/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_setup.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. From what I can see, `composePanorama` has two overloads.

```
CV_WRAP Status composePanorama(OutputArray pano);
Status composePanorama(InputArrayOfArrays images, OutputArray pano);
```

It's the second overload that we need, as the `pano` is an output parameter, which in Python is given as a return value. Unfortunately, the second overload is not marked by `CV_WRAP` which would make it available to the Python bindings. So the only solutions I can see are:

- Use an alternative stitching implementation
- Go through the C++ code of the missing composePanorama implementation and reimplement it yourself in Python
- Register an issue on the Open CV Github and wait for an update
- Build Open CV yourself from source and mark the function as `CV_WRAP` (I'm not sure it is actually as simple as that)
- Work in C++ instead of Python

Although I'll be very happy if someone else can post an answer showing how to achieve this in Python without going through the complex tasks above.